# report with subreports producing blank page

Tags: subreport

iReport 4.5.1 on Windows 7

I have a report that contains 7 subreports.
This report is run for a group of data...about 10 items.
About 9 items contain 3 subreports.
The other reports are run for one specific item.

My issues are the following:

1. A blank page is being produced after each item's report is produced.
2. I would like the ietm and date to be produced on each page but it is only produced on the initial report page. How can I implement that.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as #1 above with a subreport I was using - running report independently in iReport, everything looked great, but when it was run as a subreport, a blank page appeared after each page of content.
WHat I did to fix was to make sure my subreport design was the same width as the parent report in the Page Size option, and then to ensure that the subreport element was sized to fit the parent section's width entirely. This worked for me.